# msi file isn't installed silently using /qn

Tags: installation, windows-installer

i want to create a windows application which is install a msi file silently, when i use the /qb or /qr it's work but when i tried to used /qn msi file isn't installed. below is full code
for installing silently.

```
 Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/qn /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", "C:\\WinAppDemoSetup_3.msi");
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

please resolve my problem.

Comment: Add /l*v <log_file_path> to arguments list in order to generate a log file.

Comment: can you give me an example for <log_file_path>

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you are performing a per-machine installation. Please note that if you perform this installation on Vista or newer OSes the UAC prompt will not appear, because you have a silent install, but will still work in the background and default to "No", thus causing your install to fail.

To install the application per-machine, in silent mode, you need to run your application that is launching the install as administrator, i.e. use the option "Run as administrator" to launch the application.