# Running Setup File from Bat File in Silent Mode

Tags: file, batch-file, installation, windows-installer

I have a setup file (MSI) that can be run and install properly on a win 7 64bit system. My client wants a silent install. For this, I created a bat file (see below) and passed /qn parameter which works on a Windows XP system but gives INVALID SWITCH error on Win7 64 bit. Is there any solution to this?

```
start C:\Setup1\Debug\Setup1.msi /qn
pause
REN "C:\WINDOWS\system32\FHPropertyVideoScreenSaver.exe" "FHPropertyVideoScreenSaver.scr"
```

Comment: What is the content of your bat file?

Answer (score 0):

If you type `msiexec /?` at a cmd prompt you can see the switch you need is

`/quiet - Quiet mode, no user interaction`

or you can use

`/q` with other options to specify how much interaction there is.

Answer (score 0):

The switch is correct for Windows 7 too, maybe you have a permissions problems. Check this thread: [msi file isn't installed silently using /qn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336005/msi-file-isnt-installed-silently-using-qn/14353618#14353618)

Comment: What if I am administrator on this system?

Comment: It is not enough, you still need to run the cmd.exe as admin and launch the BAT from it. You can test it.